# create a new tag under an existing tag with php, xml

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to create a new tag under the existing tag in my xml output.
The code I use:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->validateOnParse = true;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->load(http://www.xxxx.com/xmlfile.xml');
$xml_string = $xml->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

Output:

```
<Root>
  <Products>
    <Product>   
      <Images>  
            * I want to create a label here to <image> </image> *
      </Images>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Root>
```

I want to place a **"image"** tag between the tags

```
$image->appendChild($xml->createElement('Image'));
```

But I didn't get the result I wanted :)
I'm going to group the images with the Image tag, but I need to create a priority tag.

```
<images>
    <image> http://example.com/image.jpg </image>
    <image> http://example.com/image.jpg </image>
    <image> http://example.com/image.jpg </image>
</images>
```

Comment: `appendChild` adds the new child at the end, after all already existing ones. You need to use [`insertBefore`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php) instead.

Comment: $newtag = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Images')->item(0);
$newtag->parentNode->insertBefore('Image',$newtag);

Comment: Call to a member function insertBefore() on null in 
i guess i couldn't use it right

Comment: Where exactly do you want to put this `Image` element? If you want it inside the `Images` element, then appendChild _would_ be the correct method. Unclear how exactly that was not giving you the expected result then …? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Since I'm remotely accessing the xml file, I want to add a new tag between the Image tags.
As a result, it needs to be like <Images><Image></Image> </Images>.

Comment: I couldn't run it with appendChild and insertBefore functions

Comment: Well first you need to get a proper reference to the existing `Images` element. Your code shows `$image->appendChild`, but not how you created `$image`.